# Loop through the first two entries of an enumerable

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following working Handlebar code:

```
{{#each phoneNumber in switchboardEntry.sipAccount.phoneNumbers}}
  <span class="label">
    {{phoneNumber.number}}
  </span>
{{/each}}
```

But I'd like to loop just to the first two entries of `switchboardEntry.sipAccount.phoneNumbers` and not through the complete set. I found a filter example on http://emberjs.com/guides/enumerables/ but still in the Ruby thinking mode I tried to put that filter after `switchboardEntry.sipAccount.phoneNumbers` which doesn't work.

What is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: can't you just use `switchboardEntry.sipAccount.phoneNumbers[0]` and `switchboardEntry.sipAccount.phoneNumbers[1]` in this case?

Comment: @FinnMacCool doing it that way is not that flexible if he later wants 3 or 4 items in the list. Also duplicate code :)

Comment: yeah, IF he's planning to change it later, your solution is definitely better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a computed property to `sipAccount` model.

Something like this maybe:

```
App.SipAccount = DS.Model.extend({
    phoneNumbers: DS.hasMany('App.PhoneNumbers'),

    phoneNumberShortList: Ember.computed(function() {
        var phoneNumbers = this.get('phoneNumbers');
        return phoneNumbers.slice(0,2);
    }).property('phoneNumbers.@each.number')
});
```

**Update**

The Handlebars code would then be:

```
{{#each phoneNumber in switchboardEntry.sipAccount.phoneNumberShortList}}
  <span class="label">
    {{phoneNumber.number}}
  </span>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: What is the `property('phoneNumbers.@each.number')` part for? Is it just a name?

Comment: It is telling Ember to fetch the number property of each of the phoneNumbers.

If you had simply written property('phoneNumbers') then rendering of your Handlerbars template {{phoneNumber.number}} would resolve to undefined. Only the property id would exist.

If you would also need to display e.g. the property label it should be: property('phoneNumbers.@each.number', 'phoneNumbers.@each.label')

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="label">
  {{switchboardEntry.sipAccount.phoneNumbers.0.number}}
</span>

<span class="label">
  {{switchboardEntry.sipAccount.phoneNumbers.1.number}}
</span>
```

OR

```
{{#with switchboardEntry.sipAccount.phoneNumbers}}
  <span class="label">
    {{0.number}}
  </span>

  <span class="label">
    {{1.number}}
  </span>
{{/with}}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNr6C/)